# Local variable not being passed to partial template by render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, partial-views

I don't seem to be able to pass a variable to my partial template in rails (2.3.5). My code is as follows;

In the main view .html.erb file:

```
<% f.fields_for :payments do |payment_form| %>
    <%= render 'payment', {:f => payment_form, :t => "test" } %>
<% end %>
```

and in the _payment.html.erb file:

```
<%= t %>
```

produces a `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` error. The payment_form object is being passed to the partial as f without any problems. I've tried a number of variations on the above syntax (e.g. `:locals => {:f => payment_form, :t => "test" }` without success. I presume I'm doing something pretty basic wrong but just can't see it.

Comment: Do you render `payment` somwhere else, without `:t` as part of you locals?

Comment: Aah yes I did (although I had to think about if for a while). This is a nested form partial that I'm rendering and just after I have <%= link_to_new_nested_form "Additional payment", f, :payments %>. Obviously this renders the partial (although it is hidden away in javascript until needed). Thanks. Why not put an answer in so I can accept it and send some rep your way!

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because t() is a reserved view helper method used for I18n.  Just rename it to something more descriptive

Comment: Nope, it didn't matter what I called it, it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
render :partial => 'payment', :locals => {:t => 'test'}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. The :partial => 'payment' is just a long way of saying 'payment' (as of Rails 2.3) and the :locals hash is missing the :f => payment_form. Thanks for looking at my question though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried
`<%= render 'payment', :f => payment_form %>`

I'm not sure what the :t is for, but rails is obviously saying that you should only be passing in one extra parameter with the wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) error.

Comment: The t was just a way of testing the expression before I passed through the actual variable I wanted (which I hadn't fully created yet). The actual solution is described in the comments of the question thanks to Vlad Romascanu making me look a little closer. There was, in fact, nothing wrong with my expression, I was just calling the partial elsewhere without realising it.